# Template URL redirection generating ImportError "no module named" error in Django 1.6

Tags: django, django-templates

I'm trying to migrate my application from Django 1.0 to 1.6 and am running into a problem rendering templates with URL redirections.

My application structure is:

```
mysite
   settings.py
   urls.py
   myapp
    urls.py
    views.py
    etc.
```

myapp.urls contains:

```
from mysite.myapp import views
urlpatterns = patterns('',
    # Login/Logout/Registration
    url(r'^login/$', views.login, name="login"),
    url(r'^registration/$', views.registration, name="registration"),
)
```

When I browse to /login, the URL is mapped correctly and invokes the view.  However, when the view attempts to render its template, it generates this error:

```
ImportError at /login
No module named myapp
```

and points to this redirection syntax in the template:

```
<a href="{% url 'registration' %}">
```

I can browse to /registration without errors, so it has something to do with resolving back to the URL.

It must be something simple, but I'm stumped. Any suggestions would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Finally tracked down the problem.  What I had coded was correct.  However, there were some other url patterns at the bottom of my url.py file that I had not converted to 1.6. For example

```
url(r'/schedule/$', 'schedule_list'),
```

And when the URL resolver looked for a reverse match, it apparently looped through the url patterns starting at the bottom and errored immediately. I guess I assumed it would either start at the top of the url patterns or there was some sort of lookup table that mapped names back to urls.

Answer (score 0):

Project layout was [changed in django 1.4](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.7/releases/1.4/#updated-default-project-layout-and-manage-py).

Delete `mysite` part of the module name in `myapp/urls.py`.  It should be:

```
from myapp import views
```